# Code First DbMigration when introduce inheritence

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, code-first

I have two tables: `Animals` and `Cats`. Both are filled with data.
In the code, we have separate classes `AnimalModel` and `CatModel`.

```
public class AnimalModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Name {get;set;}
}

public class CatModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Name {get;set;}
    public string FurColor {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to refactor my code by introducing `inheritance`.

```
public class AnimalModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Name {get;set;}
}

public class CatModel : AnimalModel
{
    public string FurColor {get;set;}
}
```

I think this is a rather difficult task, how could I migrate database in optimal way? Does anyone have experience in this case?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a difficult task, and your current suggested model is what you need. Later you can add CatModel to the database like this:

```
dbcontext.AnimalModels(CatModelInstance);
```

To retrieve the list of CatModels you can use this:

```
dbcontext.AnimalModels
         .OfType<CatModel>()
         .ToList();
```

You can read also this : https://practiceaspnet.wordpress.com/2015/04/09/implementing-inheritance-in-entity-framework/